# Python script converted to exe doesn´t do anything

Tags: python, python-3.x, exe, pyinstaller

I have a python3 script that I want to convert to exe file. It has 2 command line arguments and when I convert it to exe using pyinstaller and run it as exe doesn´t print anything.

The script is like this:

```py
import glob
import os
import time
import re
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
import collections

start_time = time.time()
argument1 = sys.argv[1]
argument2 = sys.argv[2:]
argument2 = [w + "f" for w in argument2]

print(argument1)
print("================================================")
print(argument2)

### Some other commands ..
```

I run the script successfully in python doing like this:

```
python3 myscript.py abc 1234 8837 828
```

but after converting to exe sending these commands

```
pyinstaller --onefile -w -F tst.py
pyinstaller --onefile -w tst.py
```

and run it like this:

```
myscript.exe abc 1234 8837 828
```

doesn´t print anything.

How to fix this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use --console instead of -w.

`pyinstaller --onefile --console tst.py`

Comment: Thanks so much. I needed to reinstall python and do several tests and finally worked as you suggested. I even was able to add an icon running this `pyinstaller.exe --onefile --console --windowed --icon="someicon.ico" script.py` but the option to avoid show terminal windows when I do double click on exe file didn't work. I think the option is `--windowed` but when double click the terminal is shown. Maybe you know the correct way to disable launch terminal when double click the exe file. Thanks

Comment: As i understand, you have a program with a GUI and also want to see some logs on console, right? I think that a posible solution will be to change the .py extension with .pyw. Also you need to change the spec file.

Comment: Actually is a command line script, not a GUI. The script accepts command line arguments. For now, only want to disable launch window when double click on exe file.